# Why does my Python code print the extra characters "ï»¿" when reading from a text file?

Tags: python, file-handling

```
try:
    data=open('info.txt')
    for each_line in data:
        try:
            (role,line_spoken)=each_line.split(':',1)
            print(role,end='')
            print(' said: ',end='')
            print(line_spoken,end='')
        except ValueError:
            print(each_line)
    data.close()
except IOError:
     print("File is missing")
```

When printing the file line by line, the code tends to add three unnecessary characters in the front, namely "ï»¿".

**Actual output:**

```
ï»¿Man said:  Is this the right room for an argument?
Other Man said:  I've told you once.
Man said:  No you haven't!
Other Man said:  Yes I have.
```

**Expected output:**

```
Man said:  Is this the right room for an argument?
Other Man said:  I've told you once.
Man said:  No you haven't!
Other Man said:  Yes I have.
```

Comment: Your file is probably encoded in UTF-8 __with__ BOM. If this isn't what you want, encode it _without_ BOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove ï»¿ from the beginning of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-%c3%af-from-the-beginning-of-a-file)

Comment: @MarcB Not a dupe of that; Python is not PHP, and has better options for handling the UTF-8 BOM. OP, pass `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to your `open()` call.

Comment: Yes, Vincent is right. That's typical for the [Byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: @senshin it worked, Thanks. 'code' data=open('sketch.txt',encoding='utf-8-sig')

Comment: @senshin is there a way to make this encoding default??

Comment: @vrkratheesh Not that I know of. You could obviously create a wrapper for `open`, e.g. `my_open = functools.partial(open, encoding='utf-8-sig')` and use that instead. (Ideally, you would just not encode your UTF-8 files with BOM, since UTF-8 is endianness-independent and doesn't need a BOM. Though if you're getting your files from some external source, I suppose that's not any easier.)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Instead of opening the file with the default encoding (which is `'utf-8'`), use `'utf-8-sig'`, which expects and strips off the [UTF-8 Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), which is what shows up as `ï»¿`.

That is, instead of

```
data = open('info.txt')
```

Do

```
data = open('info.txt', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Note that if you're on Python 2, you should see e.g. [Python, Encoding output to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17577727/) and [Convert UTF-8 with BOM to UTF-8 with no BOM in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8898294/). You'll need to do some shenanigans with `codecs` or with `str.decode` for this to work right in Python 2. But in Python 3, all you need to do is set the `encoding=` parameter when you open the file.

Comment: even after using this encoding i am still getting \ufeff in front of some line, any idea why ?

Comment: @Amrit The BOM should only occur at the start of a text stream. So, if you're seeing it in the middle, then it's probably meant to be a [zero-width no-break space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner) in legacy Unicode text. I believe it was used in Indian scripts like Devanagari. Or you have a file that's made up of a bunch of "utf-8-sig" files concatenated together.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem when dealing with excel csv files. Initially I had saved my file from the drop down choices as a .csv utf-8(comma delimited) file. Then I saved it as just a .csv(comma delimited) file and all was well. Perhaps there might be something similar issue with a .txt file

Answer (score 0):

When I had this happen, it only happened to the very first line of my CSV, both reading and writing. For what I was doing, I just made a "sacrificial" entry at the first location so that those charatcers would get added to my sacrifical entry and not any of the ones I cared about. Definitley not a robust solution but was quick and worked for my purposes.