# Python - Remove special character from csv file import into PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, encoding, python-import

I would like to import my csv file into Postgresql using Python.
The import works well. However, when I display the imported data, I find a special symbol on the first line and first column.
I tried to solve the problem by adding the encoding in my python code but nothing has to do.
Here is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import csv
import io
f = io.open(r'C:\\list.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
curs.copy_from(f, 'list', sep=';')
conn.commit()
```

Here is the symbol or special character:

```
ï»¿
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are picking up the [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).

In order to have the io module expect and strip off the BOM try changing your encoding to `utf-8-sig`:

```
f = io.open(r'C:\\list.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399172/why-does-my-python-code-print-the-extra-characters-%C3%AF-when-reading-from-a-tex).

Comment: It works perfectly.
Thank you for your help and for the link to Byte order mark.