# Importing Data from CSV without Byte Order Markers

Tags: python, csv, byte-order-mark

I am importing data from a csv. The first line of data is bringing in "ï»¿0". The first line in the csv is 0 and I made sure that nothing was in front of the numbers. How can i get rid of ï»¿ ?

```
with open('C:\\Users\jez40\Desktop\Tide_Data.csv', 'r') as data_file:
     data = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=',')
     for i in data:
     t = i[0]
```

here are the first few lines of the csv: 
0, 1388.143433
5, 1388.143433
10, 1388.14624
15, 1388.147217
20, 1388.150024

Comment: Can you share your csv or a sample of it?

Comment: 0,1388.143433
5,1388.143433
10,1388.14624
15,1388.147217
20,1388.150024

The first few lines

Comment: are those rows or columns or what? can you add them to your question so everyone can see.

Comment: Is it a Word document? A Unicode byte order mark?

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information to it. Comments are not a good place to include code.

Comment: this is a csv file i made in excel but the data that i posted is copied/ pasted from notepad++

Comment: it looks like after changing the encoding to utf-8, i did not get the BOM. Thank you

Comment: I was just about to suggest that. If you feel you have answered your own question, feel free to post an answer for others.

Comment: Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399172/why-does-my-python-code-print-the-extra-characters-%C3%AF-when-reading-from-a-tex.