# How to deal with with weird characters (ï»¿) in first column, first row of CSV?

Tags: csv, date, time

I'm trying to convert the dates in the first column of a CSV file into a tuple so I can then find the difference between all of the dates in that column and the current date, but I'm getting this error:

```
"ValueError: time data 'ï»¿2023-04-05' does not match format '%Y,%d,%m'"
```

This what I have so far:

```py
from csv import reader
from datetime import datetime

# open file in read mode
with open("food.csv", "r") as read_obj:
    # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    # Iterate over each row in the csv using reader object

    for row in csv_reader:
        # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv

        date_str = row[0].strip("-")
        fmt = "%Y,%d,%m"

        date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt)

        t_tuple = date_obj.timetuple()

        print(t_tuple)
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my Python code print the extra characters "ï»¿" when reading from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399172/why-does-my-python-code-print-the-extra-characters-%c3%af-when-reading-from-a-tex)

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro for the linked answer, that should solve it.